# fcitx: Working Chinese input in Ubuntu 16.04 (fix or find)

Tags: wubi, ibus, input-language, input, chinese

### Non-working softwares:

After installing the built-in Wubi option and one third-party, listed here:

1. Wubihaifang86;
2. ibus's Wubi-Jidan86.

I looked for a few other options but could not find anything I could install.

### The problem:

In the two mentioned above, if you type more than one hanzi's pinyin, the select table disappears.

### Typical WUBI:

In normal Chinese Wubi input, you type the word and then select the hanzi associated with the word.  If you type a sentence, you can select each of the possible words (words appear first) or possible hanzi (the possibilities for the current hanzi appear after all the word candidates).  For example, if I type "wode jia shi dafang", I would then type "1 1 1 42" meaning `first word, first word, first word, fourth character and second character`.

### No workaround:

So, I'm looking for a Wubi that has the typical behavior.  If I type a word, such as dafang, I should see all the candidates for the entire word "dafang" (maybe 10 possibilities would appear).  Instead, I type daf, and the table disappears; furthermore, if I type only da, then there are hundreds of possibilities (so, there's no good workaround).  The best I can do is use an online conversion tool, which requires VPN (a whole second set of problems).

Comment: I noticed sometimes if you type a word like "dal", in which `da` is the first character and `l` is the beginning fo the second character, some whole-word matches appear.  So, I have reason to believe that the user-input compare dictionary is just very small and does not have any candidates.  If I ever type the second letter in a second character, however, the table disappears (as if there are no word candidates in the dictionary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Useful link:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/2-best-chinese-pinyin-im-ubuntu-16-04/

### My guide (with changes)--Ubuntu-Mate 16.04:

1. Open terminal (<kbd>ctrl-alt-t</kbd>) and type `sudo apt install fcitx fcitx-googlepinyin fcitx-table-wbpy fcitx-pinyin fcitx-sunpinyin` followed by your password. //fcitx is the main, and the others are virtual keyboard options I think.
2. Press <kbd>super</kbd> to open your launcher and launch `Language Support`. //sorry, I don't know a terminal solution yet: I hope that I can find one in the near future.  **Ubuntu might need to install Language Support on first run: just click *`yes`* and wait then proceed to step three.**
3. Set `Keyboard input method system:` to `fcitx`.
4. Close the dialog and **restart your computer**.  This seems to be a necessary step; however, relogging might be enough (not tested).
5. Right-click the new keyboard icon in the tray.  One of two things might happen:

   **a.** You can click "configure"; or,

   **b.** You need to click on your default language before you see **a.**, and then you'll see **a.**.
6. Click `+` and detoggle `Only Show Current Language`; scroll to the very tippy bottom and select a non-keyboard option (Wubi--works, tested--, Google Pinyin, Pinyin, Shuangpin, or Sunpinyin). //I did not test any of the methods other than Wubi.
7. Go to `Global Config` and change `Extra key for trigger input method` to <kbd>Alt_L_Shift</kbd> (this is my personal preference, and the default <kbd>L_Shift</kbd> is an inane decision for a default setting; however, that's the default that's forced down people's throats by Microsoft).  Unless you regularly use three or more languages, you might want to disable the trigger and also the scroll-through.
8. Before the keyboard shortcut works, you'll need to <kbd>right-click</kbd> the keyboard icon in the tray and select `input method > Wubi Pinyin`.

This is 100% working for me; however, before doing this, I tried the programs mentioned in the question itself.  So, if installing those programs or their sub-components is required for success, please notify me via comment for an update.  Meanwhile, if I notice after removing those packages that some aspect was necessary, I will send an update.  Good luck and enjoy using PRC Pinyin.